# How to print a list in reverse order (from last to first item) using while and for in loops

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print a list in reverse order (from last to first item) using while and for in loops using python

I have tried slice operator[::] to get shallow copy and reverted the list

```
lst = [10,"apples",3/4,'V']

for i in lst[::-1]:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

Is there any other means apart from `[::-1]` and `reverse()` method

Comment: Hi. Could you elaborate why you need a different solution? Do yo u want the most pythonic solution or what would a good solution look like?

Comment: You mention `reverse`, is that `list.reverse`? Because there is also `reversed()` (with a "d"), which takes any sequence and goes over it in reverse direction: `for i in reversed(lst): ...`

Comment: @L3viathan, thanks i was expecting this reversed().